# Execute some threads after other threads are completed using ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I'm using ThreadPool to download multiple files from a server. I have a list of files to be downloaded, of which some files are of huge size. I want to download these huge files after downloading other small-sized files. And, I'm using `WebClient.DownloadFile()`.

Currently I'm using `Thread.Join(time)` to start the threads for huge files to start after some time. But there is no guarantee that the other downloads would have been completed by that time. The value for `time` will vary depending on the network speed.

Is there a better solution to handle this? Please help.

Comment: Which version of .net framework are you using? You could look at Task Parallel Library and use ContinueWith on tasks for your requirements.

Comment: Am using .Net framework 3.5..

Comment: If you are starting these downloads (for small or large files) in separate threads, then you could try to start each thread one after the other. Have a main thread which uses signalling or notifications from the other child threads (for downloads) and then launches a new thread.

Comment: You mean to say, I need to have two separate lists for small and large files and carry out the download in 2 separate threads, one after the other?

Answer (score 0):

Use a ManualResetEvent object and set it inside your process and wait for all reset events. Something like this:

```
public void DispatchWork(IEnumerable<string> worklist)
    {
        var resetEvents = new List<ManualResetEvent>();
        var batch = 100;
        foreach (work in worklist)
        {
            var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            resetEvents.Add(resetEvent);

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((a) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // do work
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // do something
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (resetEvent != null) resetEvent.Set();
                }
            });
        }
        foreach (var resetEvent in resetEvents)
        {
            resetEvent.WaitOne();
            resetEvent.Dispose(); // todo: use try-finally
        }

        resetEvents.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sando,I'm already using ManualResetEvent... How to distinguish the reset events from the small files to start the download for large files?

Comment: Use a waitevent to communicate "end of small files". In the large file thread use waitone() and set this event after all small files have complete